# Exporting asterisk cdr to phpmyadmin

Tags: asterisk

I'm working on a PHP probject using Asterisk.I need to store Asterisk CDR in a database .I want to know how could I connect Asterisk to phpmyadmin.I installed Asterisk on centos 6( which is installed on virtual box) and phpmyadmin is installed on another system.

Comment: Asterisk CDR files seem to be comma-separated files, so Google `mysql import csv` will get you started.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application to help an administrator manage a MySQL or MariaDB database. It can't help you interface with an application; you'd need a library function of your language to do that, or in the case of an already-developed application like Asterisk, a library or plugin like arheops mentions. What you're asking makes no real sense because phpMyAdmin doesn't expose any external API for your application to access, and as far as I can tell arheops' answer is the best because such support is (apparently) built right in to Asterisk. Perhaps you can explain further why that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk support direct mysql cdr log. So no need do anything like that

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+mysql

Comment: tks , I know that but I want to do it like what I mention

Comment: If so, see cdr_custom_csv.conf, it have list of field and allow change order.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the *cdr_mysql* module. It's in the *addons* category.

Configuration is at **/etc/asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf**:

```
[global]
dbname = asteriskcdrdb
user = asterisk
password = supersecret
charset = utf8
table = cdr
;timezone = UTC
;compat = no
hostname = 127.0.0.1
port = 3306
```

To check if the module is loaded:

```
asterisk*CLI> cdr show status
Call Detail Record (CDR) settings
----------------------------------
  Logging:                    Enabled
  Mode:                       Simple
  Log unanswered calls:       No
  Log congestion:             No

* Registered Backends
  -------------------
    mysql
```

To check if connection succeeded:

```
asterisk*CLI> cdr mysql status
Connected to asteriskcdrdb on 127.0.0.1 using table cdr for 8 days, 12 hours, 8 minutes, 38 seconds.
  Wrote 0 records since last restart.
```